# Elements overlapping while resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got problem on my blog page 2 elements are overlapping no matter what I do. I tried to make elements "block", "inline-block" and there are no any difference. Tried to make it with margin left, right, padding and nothing...

Here is the result when you resize the window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb0t7.jpg

And here is my code:

PS: I don't want to use queries because I must make like 6-7 for different browser sizes, please help :)

```css
/***********************************************
                Search-Trigger
************************************************/
.search-trigger {
  position: absolute;
  right:0.5em;
  top: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor:pointer;
  cursor:hand;
display:block;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .search-trigger {
    right: 0.8em;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width:783px){
.search-trigger{
top:26px;
}
}
.search-trigger:before {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  font-family: "ElegantIcons";
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  content: "\55";
}
.search-trigger:before::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.search-trigger.search-form--active:before {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  line-height: .9em;
  content: "\4d";
} 
/***********************************************
                Tablet-menu-icon
************************************************/
.tablet-icon{
  position: absolute;
display:block;
left:90%;
  top: 23px;
  width: 40px;
}
.tablet-icon:before{
  width: 100%;
font-size:1.6em;
display:block;
  font-family: "ElegantIcons";
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  content: "\61";
}
.tablet-icon:before::after{
clear:both;
  content: "";
}
.tablet-icon.form-active:before{
position:relative;
top:6px;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  line-height: .9em;
  content: "\4d";
}
@media screen and (min-width:1001px){
.tablet-icon{
display:none;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width:783px){
.tablet-icon{
top:19px;
}
```

```html
<span class="tablet-icon"></span>
<a id="search-trigger" class="search-trigger"></a>
     <?php get_search_form(); ?>
```